# How to get number of visits for a facebook page using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get number of **Page visits(by unique users)** for a Facebook page for the particular day or Week , i hope you know that some of metrics in insights have removed so i'm search for apt metric to show the Page visit count for the day.

i have gone through some of metrics similar to my requirement like (page_engaged_users, Page_impressions etc),

but i'm confused to choose the best one to fit to my requirement.

Comment: velan 
after reading DMCS answer i found that the thing you looking is deprecated so do you like [flag counter](http://www.flagcounter.com/) or any other hidden counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stat you're looking for appears to be deprecated.

> **page_active_users**     The number of people who have interacted with or viewed your Page or its posts. This includes interactions from Fans
>   and non-Fans. (deprecated)    *day, week, month*

However here's some that look promising that you didn't mention

**page_views**  Page views  *day*

**page_views_unique**   Page Views from users logged into Facebook  *day*

Comment: Thank you very much @DMCS  actually i had this metric in my mind though i felt  its better to ask some one expert in this anyway thanks to all who spend your valuable time for me, and also  thanks for   danish Iqbal and skolima.

Comment: Is it possible only for pages (fan pages etc) or also for profiles?